# Jsf Omnifaces After sessiontimeout called unload throught Jaas the result is white screen Empty Result

Tags: jsf, wildfly, session-timeout, jaas, omnifaces

I don't know exactly what is in the background, and I'd like to know :).

Reproduction steps:

1. get main page
2. Jaas redirect to Login page
3. Login.
4. Landed on a stateful page!
5. wait sessiontimeout
6. Refresh the page
7. Jaas redirect to Login page
8. Login.
9. Landed on white screen. (But after reload is all OK!)

By debug I remarked, After second login the unload

```
private UIViewRoot unloadView(FacesContext context, String viewId) {
    UIViewRoot createdView = createView(context, viewId);
    ResponseStateManager manager = getRenderKit(context).getResponseStateManager();

    if (restoreViewRootState(context, manager, createdView)) {
        context.setProcessingEvents(true);
        context.getApplication().publishEvent(context, PreDestroyViewMapEvent.class, UIViewRoot.class, createdView);
        Hacks.removeViewState(context, manager, viewId);
    }
    else if (isSessionNew(context)) {
        redirectPermanent(context, getRequestURIWithQueryString(context));
    }

    responseComplete();   // This row return with empty page
    return createdView;
}
```

I think second time the unload post is catched by JAAS, not the page GET.
But I don't know why.

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is in client side. There is a JS method, which exactly called after sessiontimeout.

I put this row in that method:

```
OmniFaces.Unload.disable();
```